# Multithreading Random.NextDouble()

Tags: .net, multithreading, random, generator

Which error/problems (if any) are to be expected, if NextDouble() of the same System.Random instance is called from multiple threads concurrently - without any locking ?

Comment: write your own random w/ interlocked setting of seed. If you have good seed writing a concurrent "linear congruential generator" is very easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, `System.Random` **is not thread-safe**.
For a longer answer see [this awesome post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx) which explains the issue in details.

Answer (score 1):

You could corrupt the object. The `Random` object uses an internal array of seed values, and calling an of the `Next` update that array.

Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no guarantee of thread safety, there is no defined or sensible way of answering "nothing", "anything", and "boom" are all valid answers, and indeed it could change between versions, platforms, architecture, etc.

Have you considered making it [ThreadStatic] so each thread can have an isolated version automatically? (initialisation should probably be double-checked per thread).

Comment: +1 for the ThreadStatic suggestion. The accepted answer leads to the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell without reverse engineering the implementation entirely. However, one thing that could happen is that the same "random" number be returned multiple times in a row (across multiple threads).